# How to get Home bar on older iPads with Home button?

Tags: iphone, ipad

On my iPhone, I have a Home bar (at the bottom of my screen and no Home button and I find this very good).

Therefore, I would like to know if this is possible to do on an iPad (6th generation, running iPadOS 16.2). I know it is possible on the latest versions, but I don't know for this one. If it's possible, how to enable it?

Here is a screenshot of my iPhone with the Home bar:

[image].

And here is the one from my iPad without Home bar:

[image].

Comment: Your iPad should have a similar home bar (Dock as I understand it) as well. Can you share a screenshot of your iPhone and iPad screens?

Comment: Also, which version of iPadOS is running on the iPad?

Comment: @nohillside , I use iPadOS 16.1.1

Comment: @NimeshNeema , I added screenshots as an edit to my question.

Comment: Doesn't that home bar come in tandem with Face ID? If you have Touch ID you have a button. [I seem to recall from the 24h I had a Face ID phone before sending it back & vowing never to use one ever again :P There isn't one on an SE2020, even though it's new enough.

Comment: @Tetsujin , yes indeed my iPhone has FaceID and has a home bar. I want to have one on an iPad that comes without it by default. For example, iPad Pro 2022 has one by default (and no home button).

Comment: You have a button or a bar, not both. The bar is a very poor substitute for the button, imnsho.

Comment: @Tetsujin , are you sure it isn't possible to have both a bar and a button?

Comment: Why would it be? They only had to put the horrible bar kludge in the UX when they took away the perfectly serviceable button. At the same time they punched a hole in the screen & tried to tell us it was 'better'. Someone at Apple has lost the plot in recent years.

Comment: xD @Tetsujin you may be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Home bar visibility can not be toggled via any setting within iOS.

A Home bar is enabled by default and only available on any iOS/iPadOS device that lacks a physical Home button.

While all the iPhone models that lack a Home button, does feature Face ID as a mechanism for biometric authentication, the same may not be true for iPad. Some of the iPad that lack Face ID may still feature Home bar due to absence of Home button.

In addition to serving the function of helping users to navigate to the Home screen, Home bar enables additional features such swiping left or right to switch between recently used apps.

Answer (score 1):

That home bar is a function of two things:

- iOS version
- Presence of face ID technology

The first is obvious, the OS must support it.  The second, you must have Face ID because that home bar is a way to activate the biometric authentication *without* having a physical button as the iPad 6th gen does.

Comment: So it's not possible?

Comment: No.  It’s not a preference to be toggled; is an OS and hardware convention.